# Confusion about divergence of point particle

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics

So in the Griffiths textbook he introduces the dirac delta function by attempting to calculate the divergence of $\frac{\hat r}{r^2}$. When performing the divergence calculation, we get $0$ everywhere, but when taking the Gauss integral we get $4\pi$. This is supposedly because of the singularity at $r=0$.

However, where exactly are we going wrong, and which answer is right?
 People often write the divergence as $4\pi d(s)$, but how do we even know that the Gauss integral is meaningful with the singularity? Finally, does this only happen with $\frac{1}{r^2}$ or does it happen for all $\frac{1}{r^n}$, $n>0$?

I am confused by what exactly is going wrong: which answer of divergence is "correct" and why?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Physics SE ! Would you please format your question with MathJax? It makes your questions more attractive and also eady to read.

Comment: The integral itself is well-defined because there are no singularities on the domain of integration.  Whether the divergence theorem holds is another matter - the answer is essentially yes, but it requires you to generalize to the notion of a [distributional derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)#Derivatives_of_distributions) - which is what physicists secretly do all the time.

Comment: @J. Murray Secretly... Hushhhh!

Answer (score 2):

***The correct answer is $4\pi$*** ( *More specifically $4\pi\delta ^3 (\textbf{r})$*)

The *divergence differential* is not radius independent and thus at $r=0$, we encounter a "division by zero" leading to a solution that is incorrect. Although it is true that the divergence is $0$ everywhere, it is not so at $r=0$.

On the other hand, we see that the *divergence integral* is independent of the radius of the sphere, and thus it gives the value of the divergence correctly as $4\pi$.

Combining these two facts, we see that the divergence is a function which has its value 0 everywhere, except at the very centre where it suddenly spikes to a constant value of $4\pi$. And that's the definition of a ***Dirac Delta Function*** ( a function that is $0$ everywhere, but suddenly blips up to some value at some point, and then is $0$ again everywhere ).

And that's how you get the value of $4\pi\delta ^3 (\textbf{r})$ .

And for $n>2$, the divergence function (both the *differential* as well as the *integral*)  becomes radius dependent, making the "division by zero" more explicit, creating all sorts of problems (There is no escape now). (You can even prove that Gauss' Theorem is invalid for $n\ne 2$ )

Cheers!!